# Hardware error in syslog after gaming

Tags: linux, hardware

Sometimes when I'm playing a game I'll get the following message from syslogd:

```
[16789.554414] [Hardware Error]: Corrected error, no action required.
[16789.554418] [Hardware Error]: CPU:0 (15:2:0) MC2_STATUS[-|CE|MiscV|-|-|-|-|CECC]: 0x98254000000c0176
[16789.554421] [Hardware Error]: MC2 Error: VB Data ECC or parity error.
[16789.554422] [Hardware Error]: cache level: L2, tx: DATA, mem-tx: EV
[16790.541765] [Hardware Error]: Corrected error, no action required.
[16790.541785] [Hardware Error]: CPU:1 (15:2:0) MC2_STATUS[Over|CE|MiscV|-|AddrV|-|-|CECC]: 0xdc2540a000040136
[16790.541789] [Hardware Error]: MC2_ADDR: 0x000000026a71c638
[16790.541791] [Hardware Error]: MC2 Error: Fill ECC error on data fills.
[16790.541793] [Hardware Error]: cache level: L2, tx: DATA, mem-tx: DRD
```

I have an FX-9590 with 16GB of DDR3-2133. No problems actually occur so it's not really inconvenient but if nothing else I'd like to understand what's going on. I notice it mentions an ECC error. Is this just a memory error?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a power issue like reported here:

http://verahill.blogspot.de/2014/04/571-briefly-dodgyunderpowered-ups.html

Others report a BIOS problem with C6 state or a real CPU HW error. But I think power issue is the most reasonable for your description.

Comment: :/. I have a 1000W PSU and no UPS or any form of power filtering. Is there any way to diagnose this?